# Sql trigger whenever a field gets null (empty)

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have two certain fields in a sql table, **to_change** and **isn't_null**.

How should I procede if I want to make a sql trigger that will turn **to_change** into **5** whenever **isn't_null** gets **nulled out**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_field_if_other_field_is_null 
BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.to_change = IF (NEW.isnt_null IS NULL, 5, NEW.to_change);
```

On each `UPDATE` statement, this trigger changes the field "to_change" to 5, when the other field gets set to `NULL`.

Note that you need to create a similar trigger `BEFORE INSERT` if you want this logic to apply for newly inserted rows as well.

Comment: ty @kaii! what about if I also want another field to change? `CREATE TRIGGER change_field_if_other_field_is_null 
BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.to_change = IF (NEW.isnt_null IS NULL, 5, NEW.to_change), NEW.another_field = IF(NEW.isnt_null IS NULL,5,NEW.another_field);` ?